# Using infer to grab the boxed Observable value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I've created a `pipe` to convert any source to an `Observable`, as follows:

```
// If T is like an Observable it infers the inner value, otherwise it returns T
type Unobservable<T> = T extends Observable<infer R> ? R : T;

@Pipe({
  name: 'toObservable'
})
export class ToObservablePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(value: T): Observable<Unobservable<T>> {
    return isObservable(value) ? value : just(value);
  }
}
```

The functionality itself works, however I'm facing a problem with the return type. Currently it shows the following error:

> Type '(T & Observable) | Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable>'.
>     Type 'T & Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable>'.
>       Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Unobservable'.

Just to context you, the use of the pipe can be something like this:

```
<h4>Array source</h4>

<pre>{{ array | toObservable | async | json }}</pre>
```

How can I make compiler "happy"? :)

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-gijpz4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an overload instead, as the [**@angular/AsyncPipe**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.11/packages/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.ts#L88-L92):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { isObservable, Observable, of as just } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({
  name: 'toObservable'
})
export class ToObservablePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(value: null): null;
  transform<T>(value: undefined): undefined;
  transform<T>(value: Observable<T> | null | undefined): Observable<T> | null | undefined;
  transform<T>(value: T): Observable<T> | null | undefined;
  transform(value: Observable<any> | null | undefined): any {
    // can be also if (value === null || value === undefined) ...
    if (value == null) return value;

    return isObservable(value) ? value : just(value);
  }
}
```

[**`WORKING DEMO`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-msen2a)

---

**Some test cases**:

```
const obj = { label: 1 };

// Error!
new ToObservablePipe().transform(null).subscribe(response => console.log(response));

// Error!
new ToObservablePipe().transform(undefined).subscribe(response => console.log(response));

// Inferred as string
new ToObservablePipe().transform('').subscribe(response => console.log(response));

// Inferred as number
new ToObservablePipe().transform(0).subscribe(response => console.log(response));

// Inferred as { label: number }
new ToObservablePipe().transform(just(obj)).subscribe(response => console.log(response));

// Inferred as { label: number }[]
new ToObservablePipe().transform([obj]).subscribe(response => console.log(response));

// Inferred as { label: number }
new ToObservablePipe().transform(obj).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve the same result, by this way without using infer.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { isObservable, Observable, of as just } from "rxjs";

@Pipe({
  name: "toObservable"
})
export class ToObservablePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(value: T): T | Observable<T> {
    return isObservable(value) ? value : just(value);
  }
}
```

but if you want to use infer, I can suggest you this solution

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { isObservable, Observable, of as just } from "rxjs";

type Unobservable<T> = T extends Observable<infer R> ? R : T;
type ObservableOrAny<T> = Observable<T> | T;

@Pipe({
  name: "toObservable"
})
export class ToObservablePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(value: ObservableOrAny<T>): Observable<Unobservable<ObservableOrAny<T>>> {
    return isObservable(value) ? value : just(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, I would like to thank you for posting a reply.
*...with your return type Observable<Unobservable<T>> it becomes as Observable<Observable<whatever type is>>...* Not really! The `Unobservable` type returns (or at least it should) `T` if `T` is not an `Observable`, otherwise it returns `Observable<T>`. I did it based on this [**nice article**](https://dev.to/aexol/typescript-tutorial-infer-keyword-2cn). The whole point of the `Unobservable` (using conditional types and `infer`) is to not return an `union` type, but the correct type.

Comment: Check it yourself: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-5wxgvj The conditional type `Unobservable` takes care of the wrapped observable. Just hover the return types (`toObservable.pipe` file) in the link above.

Comment: @dev_054 ah sorry I understand it wrong at first, I have updated my answer and suggested the second solution, by creating another type for the argument type and return type

Answer (score -1):

```
type Unobservable<T> = T extends Observable<infer R> ? R : T;
```

Means `Unobservable` could be passed `<T>`'s type, or `any` since `R` can be some unknown type.

And here `transform<T>(value: T): Observable<Unobservable<T>>` You expect the return to be the same type as transform, and that wont always be the case since we are declaring it can be `any` type and ask to infer it.

To make what you have work, type transform response to any.

```
Observable<Unobservable<any>>
```

Unobservable in the end is just any type, I don understand the use for it.

Comment: Firstly, I would like to thank you for posting a reply. I guess you didn't get the point of `Unobservable` type. I created it to conditionally `infer` the type of the "boxed" value of the `Observable`. That's the whole point of Typescript's conditionally types and `infer` keyword. I don't want it to be `any` in any case, unless, of course, I pass `any` directly.

Comment: Why the downvote?? The error is telling you that the unknown type can be received. Therefore Observable<Unobservable<T>> may or may not be what you are expecting. My answer is not wrong, please explain downvote.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't downvote your answer. That being said, I explained what I want and your answer just says: "Use any" and it sure isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { isObservable, Observable, of as just } from "rxjs";

type Unobservable<T> = T extends Observable<infer R> ? R : T;

@Pipe({
  name: "toObservable"
})
export class ToObservablePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T>(value: T): Observable<Unobservable<T>> {
    return isObservable(value) ? value as Observable<Unobservable<T>> : 
just(value) as Observable<Unobservable<T>>;
  }
}
```

Casting will satisfy compiler if it is all you want.